# How to publish WCF Service Library and get transformed web.config?

Tags: wcf, web.config-transform

I have WCF Service Library project and have configured slow cheetah extension for transforming .config files.
When I run publish on the project the build output produce in bin folder appropriate dll file for the service and NameOfService.dll.config file which is transformed correctly. 
The publish process also produce .svc and web.config file. The issue is that the web.config file is not transformed.

Is it possible to get also web.config file transformed by this process and how ?